# Taking First Two Elements in List

Tags: list, dictionary, vbscript

I am trying to script a dynamic way way to only take the first two elements in a list and I am having some trouble. Below is a breakdown of what I have in my List

Declaration:

```
Set List = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

List Contents:

```
List(0) = 0-0-0-0
List(1) = 0-1-0-0
List(2) = 0-2-0-0
```

Code so far:

```
    for count = 0 To UBound(List) -1 step 1
        //not sure how to return
    next
```

What I currently have does not work.

Desired Return List:

```
 0-0-0-0
 0-1-0-0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Items method of the Dictionary. For more info see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aet97f2%28v=vs.84%29)

For example:

```
Dim a, i

a = List.Items

For i = 0 To List.Count - 1
    MsgBox(a(i))
Next i
```

or if you just want the first 2:

```
For i = 0 To 1
    MsgBox(a(i))
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

`UBound()` is for arrays, not dictionaries. You need to use the `Count` property of the Dictionary object.

```
' Show all dictionary items...
For i = 0 To List.Count - 1
    MsgBox List(i)
Next

' Show the first two dictionary items...
For i = 0 To 1
    MsgBox List(i)
Next
```